# Munsell color space, CIE, and the mysterious 1.0257

Tags: color-space, color-theory

This is an arcane question, but here's hoping.

It has been established empirically, that the luminance Y in the CIE color spaces is a function of the Munsell value V. It does not depend on hue or chroma. The function can be approximated by a 5th degree polynomial (Eq. 2 of ASTM Standard D 1535-08.)

```
double munV_to_cieY(const double V) {
    // V is in [0,10] 
    // Y is in [0,100] 
    double Y = V*(1.1914+V*(-0.22533+V*(0.23352+V*(-0.020484+V*0.00081939))));
    return Y; 
}
```

It is the case that in the Munsell renotation data, which associates HVC triples with xyY triples, the Y in xyY is effectively multiplied by a mysterious 1.0257. I have verified that that is the case. I read somewhere, years ago, that the mystery number is due to some kind of mistake, but that is all I remember.

What was the mistake?

I want to know because I have a program that maps sRGB pixels to Munsell. Should I only use the 1.0257 when processing the renotation training data? Or should I also use it in the program per se?

Can someone tell me what's up with that 1.0257, or suggest a way to find out?

EDIT: I inverted the function, using a cubic spline. When applied to the renotation data that I have, here's what I get

```
V   Y       V'     
1   1.21    1.022   
2   3.126   2.031   
3   6.55    3.037   
4   12.00   4.046   
5   19.77   5.056   
6   30.03   6.064  
7   43.06   7.076   
8   59.1    8.085   
9   78.66   9.092
```

I am trying to wrap my head around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is, the renotation Y-data are too high by a factor of 1.0257, but the quintic formula listed in the question is correct.

(The discrepancy is apparently related to the reflectance of 0.975 of magnesium dioxide, a white substance which one presumes was used somehow when analysing the color samples.)

A predecessor to the quintic above was fitted to the uncorrected renotation data. The ASTM standard contains a note to the effect that the correct quintic was obtained from the previous one by dividing the original by 1.0257 (I.e. multiplying each coefficient by 0.975.)

Answer (score 0):

In regard to Eq.2, ASTM D1535-08e1 states that:

> The coefficients of this equation are obtained from the 1943 equation
>   by multiplying each coefficient by 0.975, the reﬂectance factor of
>   magnesium oxide with respect to the perfect reﬂecting diffuser, and
>   rounding to ﬁve digits of precision.

The Munsell Renotation data commonly available through the all.dat, experimental.dat and real.dat files features CIE xyY values that are scaled by a 1 / 0.975 ±= 1.0257 factor because the reference white used for measurement was magnesium oxide.

Magnesium oxide reflectance relative to the perfect reflecting diffuser is 97.5%, thus Munsell Value (V) = 10 converts to Luminance (Y) = 100/97.5 ≈ 102.57 if magnesium oxide is the reference white.

If you are performing conversions using the Munsell Specification, e.g. **2.5R 9/2**, using ASTM D1535-08e1 practise, you do not have to scale the computed Luminance (Y) because the adopted reference white is the perfect reflecting diffuser. However, if you are directly using the Munsell Renotation CIE xyY data, you will have to scale it first accordingly to the ratio between magnesium oxide and your reference white.

Comment: I am mighty glad to hear from you about this. I see now that dividing by 1.0257 is right out. Yet frankly, I am still confused. See EDIT 2 in the original question. The inverse of the ASTM function does not restore the value of V. with great accuracy.  Is there a different renotation data set that I don't know about? I am using one called all.dat that has been on the web for a very long time.  I am not up to date with recent work on the subject. I began my project in the early 2000's, before putting it on hold because I did not have the time. I only just now brought it out of mothballs.

Comment: Now I am even confuseder. I took a look at the all.dat file I am using, for the first time in a long time. It has extrapolated values that match Munsell V = 10 with Y = 102.57.  My head is spinning.

Comment: I looked at what we have in Colour. First our inversion based on linear interpolation (https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/124f5f72c418571e41fb06d05a99c02e2b825413/colour/notation/munsell.py#L423) is much precise than what you get: `print(colour.munsell_value_ASTMD153508(colour.luminance_ASTMD153508(10)))` 10.0000002083. Second, we are not using the xyY data from the various .dat file and there is indeed a mismatch if you don't scale Y post conversion. I have opened an issue on our end (https://github.com/colour-science/colour/issues/340).

Comment: When you wrote "is much precise" did you mean "is much more precise" or "much less precise"?  I used a lot of knots, so the cubic spline will be almost perfectly the inverse of the ASTM quinitic. Given 100 as input, it will yield precisely 10.0, because 100 is a is a knot, (an end point in fact).  Please keep me informed as to what you figure out.

Comment: I was meaning "much more precise", I then might have not understood what your table represent, I thought it was roundtrip, e.g. Munsell Value ---> Luminance --> Munsell Value , can you describe the operations you went through? I will definitely look after an explanation on all this. My answer might actually be incorrect.

Comment: Sort of a round-trip, but I'm only a passenger on the first leg. :-)  Here's what I was getting at. E.g., the Y value (in the xyY)  given in the Munsell renotation data for Munsell value V=2.0 is Y=3.126. Apply the inverse of the ASTM quintic to 3.126, and obtain 2.031  .  The accuracy of the one calculation is not in question. The question is, why does it produce values that are about 1% higher than one would naively expect?

Comment: I was right on the first guess. The ASTM quintic is correct for 2 degree C illuminant.  It does not compensate for the faulty  renotation data.  Divide all the Y's in the renotation data by 1.0257. That fixes the data.  Use the ASTM quinitic and its inverse without scaling either.  You may want to modify or delete your answer.

Comment: An alternate way to fix the renotation Y's would be to calculate them afresh usiing the ASTM quintic.

Comment: I have corrected my answer in regard to the Luminance scaling. I would not say that the data is faulty, it uses a different reference white that has a lower reflectance than ASTM perfect diffuser. That makes it unsuitable for direct usage with ASTM D1535-08e1 but this not faulty per see. I was playing with some Munsell spectral data (https://www.uef.fi/web/spectral/munsell-colors-matt-spectrofotometer-measured) and for the 2.5R 9/2 patch in real.dat with [0.3220, 0.3168, 78.6600] xyY value, [ 0.3220, 0.3168, 0.76695586] scaled, the measured one is [0.32113881, 0.3168106, 71.57041158].

Comment: Reference whites do not have reflectances.

Comment: Reference white can actually be a diffuser thus with reflectance: "In measuring spectral reflectance (or transmittance) factor, the CIE recommends as reference white, the adoption of the perfect reflecting (or transmitting) diffuser." Hunt, R. W. G., & Pointer, M. R. (2011). Measuring Colour (p. 102). John Wiley & Sons, Ltd.